# Where is Python language used?

Tags: python

I am a web developer and usually use PHP, JavaScript or MySQL.
I have heard lot about Python. But I have no idea where it is used and why it is used.

Just like  PHP, ASP, ColdFusion, .NET are used to build websites, and 
C, C++, Java are used to build software or desktop apps.

Where does Python fit in this?

What can Python do that these other languages cannot do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Python started as a scripting language for Linux like Perl but less cryptic. Now it is used for both web and desktop applications and is available on Windows too. Desktop GUI APIs like GTK have their [Python implementations](http://www.pygtk.org) and Python based web frameworks like [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) are preferred by many over PHP et al. for web applications.

And by the way,

- What can you do with PHP that you can't do with ASP or JSP?
- What can you do with Java that you can't do with C++?

Comment: I think the reply is vague.

Answer (score 17):

All the languages you've mentioned are [Turing Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), so in theory there is nothing one can do and another can't. In practice of course, there are differences, especially in productivity and efficiency. Compared to C, C++ and Java, which are static typed, Python is a dynamic language and can help you write the same code in significantly fewer lines.  Python has a moto "batteries included", which means that the standard library offers all the things needed to build a complex application. Other languages would need external libraries for this. On top of this, since Python is an old and mature language (older than Java), many external libraries (for game development and scientific calculations just to mention a few) have been evolved. So Python can be used to program desktop applications and in fact in some cases more efficiently than other traditional languages.

Python is also a scripting language. This means that you can easily and quickly write scripts and simple tests with it.

More recently python is also used for web frameworks. Since there is a big code base and many python programmers, this was a logical thing to do. These web frameworks follow the practice mainly introduced by Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I have seen that Google is also using Python for complex apllication which involves scintific calculations. FOr example i have build a website in php. I want to make some calculation using python program and display page. Can i use both php and python together. I mean to say that on website where i pages are in php and i make some page like . mypage.py

Comment: There is no straightforward way to mix php and python in serving a website. You could start a python process from php. but that wouldn't be effective.

Answer (score 14):

With a few exceptions, Python is used pretty much wherever a programmer who knows Python wants to focus on solving a problem instead of struggling with implementation details.  You'll find it [in](http://www.civ4.com/) [games](http://www.eveonline.com/), [web](http://www.djangoproject.com/) [applications](http://code.google.com/appengine/), [network servers](http://www.list.org/), [scientific computing](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific), [media tools](http://www.pitivi.org/), [application scripting](http://www.autodesk.com/maya), etc.  (There's a somewhat old list of some organizations that use it [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/OrganizationsUsingPython).)  People who know it well tend to [love it](http://xkcd.com/409/) because it strikes a very rare balance of conciseness and clarity, and (perhaps to a lesser extent) because it has a rich set of useful libraries.

Some places where Python isn't used as much:

- Web browser scripts (because browsers implement JavaScript, not Python, though there are [ways around that](http://pyjs.org/))
- Large GUI applications (perhaps because good GUI bindings are relatively new)
- Graphics engines (for performance reasons, but note that Python is sometimes used for the controlling logic that makes use of a graphics engine)
- Small embedded devices (although some folks have had success with [compact](http://micropython.org/), [stripped-down](http://www.tinypy.org/) and [special-purpose](http://wiki.opensource.nokia.com/projects/Python_for_S60) implementations of Python, and we're starting to see python tools for building applications on [smart phones and tablets](http://kivy.org/).)

Comment: While I agree broadly agree and like python a lot, a feature to consider is that python is not really multi-threaded, in the sense that a python process only consumes one cpu core.  This is funny, because you may declare python threads, without being aware that they will execute all in only one core.  The implication is that, if your project is inherently asynchronous, as is a web app, and high volume, then you have to use non-blocking I/O (as node.js does). See http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/

Comment: @artejera While I appreciate your concern, your statement is wildly misleading. Please educate yourself on the GIL, as well as the situations where it can interfere with multi-threaded execution, and those where it will not. In brief: There are several python implementations that do not have a GIL, and even in CPython (which has one), programs often spend time in library code that does not hold the GIL and therefore does not block threads. Please also educate yourself on standard multiprocessing paradigms like process pools, which have been around longer than threads and work fine in python.

Comment: By the way, non-blocking I/O does nothing to take advantage of multiple CPU cores, so I don't know why you mentioned it in that comment.

Comment: Hi @forest.  Continuing with the threading topic, see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock.  Of course, designs are available to overcome this limitation.

Comment: Also interesting: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-make-Django-non-blocking

Answer (score 2):

Your categorization is not correct:

php, asp and ColdFusion are mostly used for websites, that is correct, but .net is definetly much more than asp you can build desktop applications, too ([Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/)). I don't know about ColdFusion, but PHP can also be used to write desktop applications.

On the other hand C,C++ are not really often used for web programming, But it can be used for web programming ([cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/)). Java is definetly a language to develop web applications ([spring](http://www.springsource.org/) and much more).

Python is a scripting language like PHP, Perl, Ruby and so much more. It can be used for web programming ([django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), [Zope](http://www.zope.org/), [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/), and much more). But it also can be used for desktop applications ([Blender 3D](http://www.blender.org/), or even for games [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/)).

Python can also be translated into binary code like java.

Answer (score 2):

Many websites uses Django or Zope/Plone web framework, these are written in Python.

Python is used a lot for writing system administration software, usually when bash scripts (shell script) isn't up to the job, but going C/C++ is an overkill. This is also the spectrum where perl, awk, etc stands. Gentoo's emerge/portage is one example. Mercurial/HG is a distributed version control system (DVCS) written in python.

Many desktop applications are also written in Python. The original Bittorrent was written in python.

Python is also used as the scripting languages for GIMP, Inkscape, Blender, OpenOffice, etc. Python allows advanced users to write plugins and access advanced functionalities that cannot typically be used through a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Python is used for developing sites. It's more highlevel than php.
Python is used for linux dekstop applications. For example, the most of Ubuntu configurations utilites are pythonic.

Comment: why is python more highlevel than php?

Answer (score 1):

Python is also great for scientific programs such as statistical models or physics sims.  I've done monte-carlo programs and, using the [VISUAL](http://vpython.org/) module, a 3D simulation of the Apollo mission.